# Plotting the line graph

Tags: api, google-api, google-visualization

i have this google charts call which is plotting a line graph...my question is how

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:|Jan|Feb|March|June|July&chxt=x,y&chf=bg,lg,90,efefef,0,ffffff,1&chd=s:FP9XlFP9Xl&chdl=first+data+set+label|second+data+set+label&chtt=metallica's+recent+requests&cht=lc&chs=770x300&chxr=0,10,120
```

I did some research and found that this part `chd=s:FP9XlFP9Xl` is what is doing the plotting but how...all i see is letters. Also I am specifying months like January and February ext.. how do i say that some plots in the line graph are for one month and one for another...Any help would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more information on the encoding of the google chart data here http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/data_formats.html#extended